# PyInstaller "You may load I/O plugins with the `skimage.io.use_plugin`"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

useing  Pyinstaller packages a  python script

Pyinstaller version 3.2

OS:Ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 57, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 29, in feature_extract
  File "caffe/io.py", line 295, in load_image
  File "skimage/io/_io.py", line 100, in imread
  File "skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 194, in call_plugin
RuntimeError: No suitable plugin registered for imread.

You may load I/O plugins with the `skimage.io.use_plugin` command.  A list of all available plugins can be found using `skimage.io.plugins()`.
file_test returned -1
```

I have been getting above error. Could some one please tell me how would i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to this [github issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/583), essentially the `skimage.io._plugins` submodule is making life hard for Pyinstaller.

To make sure everything you need is packaged you should have a [hook file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#understanding-pyinstaller-hooks) that contains

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files, collect_submodules

datas = collect_data_files("skimage.io._plugins")
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('skimage.io._plugins')
```

(or if you already have a hook file with these, extend the current `datas` and `hiddenimports`).